# what is the purpose of using auto when declaring variable with static_cast<>()?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, auto

Scott Meyers in his *"Effective Modern C++: 42 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of C++11 and C++14"* discusses use of `auto` in  different contexts. He makes a point that sometimes `auto` deducts incorrect type because normally, a developer would use (possibly unconsciously) implicit conversion like here:

```cpp
std::vector<bool> vec = {true, false};
bool a = vec[0]
```

while using `auto` like that:

```cpp
std::vector<bool> vec = {true, false};
auto a = vec[0]
```

would yield `a` to be `std::vector<bool>::reference` so the author proposes to cast it before assignment:

```cpp
auto a = static_cast<bool>(vec[0])
```

and I cannot understand why would I use `auto` and `static_cast<>` in this way if I can simply count on implicit conversion. I figured that maybe it is to highlight the fact that there is a conversion going  on (to note it explicitly) but it still looks like an overkill to me. What would be the advantage of such solution?

Cheers!

Comment: Some people go for the "almost always auto" idiom, so they want to use `auto` for the type. Using a `static_cast` in this context makes it clear that there's a conversion going on, and correctly deduces the type you want.

Comment: @cigien actually, author also mentions proxy classes and situations when you want to cast `float` to `double` etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of cases where `static_cast` can help reduce both compiler ambiguities and also reader ambiguities when used with `auto`.

Specifically, when considering `std::vector<bool>` in the example, I can think of two such cases:

- If this were passed to a function template that deduces the argument, you would probably rather `decltype(a)` to be a `bool` rather than some `std::__vector_bool_reference_wrapper` type, or
- If `a` were passed to a function with a signature that accepts a `bool&` or `bool*`, you would want this to be the correct type -- since implicit conversions will not occur

The above cases apply to anything that may have implicit conversions, not just `bool`/reference-wrapper.

Additionally, cases get more interesting with other types.

**Pointers:**

`nullptr` is of type `decltype(nullptr)` which is also aliased as `std::nullptr_t`. This is *not* any type `T*`. Which means you can't write code like:

```cpp
auto p = nullptr;
...
p = &a; // compile-error!
```

But instead would need:

```cpp
auto p = static_cast<T*>(nullptr);
...
p = &a; // works!
```

**Unintentional Promotions**

Unintentional promotion can produce unexpected bugs. If code is using `auto` and is relying on integer overflow, without being explicit about types, it is possible to unintentionally produce integer promotion -- which can prevent that overflow from occurring. This can produce subtle bugs in some code.

The same is likely possible with `float`/`double` promotion, though I'm having a harder time thinking of a case where such a case would be negative.

Unintended promotions can also cause compile-failures if the result is being passed to a function that expects a reference or pointer to `T` of a different type than the promoted type is (similar to the `vector<bool>` example above).

---

I'm sure other cases exist where `static_cast` is significant when used with `auto`, but in general the cases that come to mind deal with the strict typing that comes with overload resolution and template type deduction.

Other than that, there may also be cases where `static_cast` just helps the general readability of complex functions that use a lot of `auto`

Comment: I like the example with `nullptr` ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Take that as a premise: You want to use `auto` as much as possible, then

```
std::vector<bool> vec = {true, false};
auto a = vec[0];
```

will do the unexpected, while:

```
auto a = static_cast<bool>(vec[0]);
```

will get you a `bool`. I don't think the point here is to say: "Use `static_cast` together with `auto` as much as possible". But rather: "If you want to use `auto` almost always, then sometimes you have to add a `static_cast`"

> ...in this way if I can simply count on implicit conversion...

In this case yes, but then you are not using `auto`. Also consider the case when it wasn't you who used `auto`. Lets say you are given a lambda defined as:

```
auto foo = [](auto x){};
```

You cannot change its signature, hence you need to use a `static_cast` if you want to call it with `vec[0]` and get the right type deduced.

Also consider that if you do follow AAA (almost always auto) then you do want do declare all variables as `auto`. This helps to never forget to initialize a variable. If you fall back to

```
bool a = vec[0];
```

when needed, then that defeats the whole point of applying AAA in the first place. You want to be consistent and not choose `auto` vs explicit type depending on the initializer.

Comment: lambda point is insightful but it's sort of a different context. You know you have to cast your argument. And so I understand there is no other purpose than to be explicit about conversion. Both your and the other author answers are great so Im having hard time to point out the accepted answer

Comment: @Proko i added another point. Pick whichever answer you think is the best. This is not a contest ;) An informed reader will know that they need to read more than the accepted to get the whole picture. If that helps you, I like the other answer more